# Receive model from list and show the propery [javascript] [angular7]

Tags: angular, typescript, drop-down-menu, angular7

I have a list that contains object models. The model has a first name and last name.

I would like to load the models in a dropbox but see the first and last name. 
I used data binding to get the information. How do I get the model object instead of the first and last name?

This is my HTML code:

```
<select id="model" [(ngModel)]="currentSelectedModel">
  <option *ngFor="let model of modellist">{{model.firstName}}</option>
</select>
```

and typescript code:

```
currentSelectedModel = new model();
modellist = model[] = []
```

and a function that fills in the model list with 2 objects for testing.
I assume I have to change something in `<option></option>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to show first and last name, do it this way. Additionally set `model` as value by using the `[value]`-directive.

```
<select id="model" [(ngModel)]="currentSelectedModel">
    <option *ngFor="let model of modellist"
    [ngValue]="model">{{model.firstName}} {{model.lastName}}</option>
</select>
```